# Почему страница грузит долго и не добавляются шахматные фигуры?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь сделать Шахматную доску через JS. Её сделать получилось, да вот только при попытке добавить шахматные фигуры - ничего не выходит, т.к. страница долго грузится и ничего не отображает. Помогите решить проблему.

### Как я добавляю чёрные пешки на доску:

```js
var row, column;
var square;
var container = document.getElementById("container");

for (row = 0; row < 8; ++row) {
    for (column = 0; column < 8; ++column) {
        square = document.createElement("div");
        if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) {
            square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        } else {
            square.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
        }
        square.classList.add("square");
        if (row = 2) {
            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/pesh_black.png'></img>";
        }
        container.appendChild(square);
    }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 570px) {
    #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 400px;
        border: 12px solid black;
        border-radius: 6px;
        height: 400px;
    }

    .square {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
    .square img{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
    #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 200px;
        border: 12px solid black;
        border-radius: 6px;
        height: 200px;
        transform: scale(1.7);
    }

    .square {
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
    .square img{
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Шахматная доска</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="js.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### Создание шахматной доски без добавления пешек:

```js
var row, column;
var square;
var container = document.getElementById("container");

for (row = 0; row < 8; ++row) {
    for (column = 0; column < 8; ++column) {
        square = document.createElement("div");
        if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) {
            square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        } else {
            square.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
        }
        square.classList.add("square");
        container.appendChild(square);
    }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 570px) {
    #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 400px;
        border: 12px solid black;
        border-radius: 6px;
        height: 400px;
    }

    .square {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
    .square img{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
    #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 200px;
        border: 12px solid black;
        border-radius: 6px;
        height: 200px;
        transform: scale(1.7);
    }

    .square {
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
    .square img{
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Шахматная доска</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="js.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уточните заголовок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас при добавлении фигур, при проверке на номер строки, идёт присваивание и из-за этого уходит в бесконечный цикл:

```
if (row = 2) {
    // ^^^
    square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/pesh_black.png'></img>";
}
```

Comment: Оу, совсем не заметил

Comment: Такс, поменял на `==` но всё равно ничего не поменялось(

Comment: Всё, заработало) Это я забыл сохранить JS код XD